# Sharing internet connection windows-linux

Tags: connection-sharing

I have a Linux machine connected via Ethernet cable to a Windows 10 Laptop, which is connected to the internet via wifi router.

I've turned ON the "Internet connection sharing" option on the WiFi connection in the laptop. I've also configured static IP of the Linux machine so that it's in the same network with the Laptop and can see it. 
The Linux machine however still cannot access the internet.

Could you advise, is that a proper setup?